# Rails is not updating file on the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filesystems

I have `_form` partial for loading form content on the index page but I cannot update it with new code because it looks like Rails is not noticing any changes on the file. I tried to restart the server, cleared browser cache, checked application in Safari and Chrome, checked it in Incognito mode, tried to delete and make the same file again, checked this file twice in both Sublime Text and TextEdit but everything looks okay.

I checked this settings in `config/environments/development.rb` too:

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

But still nothing.

Comment: You could try to clear the Rails cache (using console): `Rails.cache.clear`

Comment: @Mat Still nothing.

Comment: Usually when this happens to me, it's cause I'm editing the wrong file.

Comment: You wrote... "on the server". You could check if that specific file is really on the remote server. A failed deploy? Forgot to commit something? It happens sometimes

Comment: @Mat It's local web server, my mistake.